# Internal style and script in head are not applied

Tags: javascript, css, joomla3.0

I am using Joomla and the T3 template. I added the following "Custom Code" before the `</head>` tag:

```
<style type="text/stylesheet">
  div.t3-sidebar.t3-sidebar-right{
    background: #F8F8F8 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    border: 1px solid rgb(238, 238, 238);
    border-radius: 20px;
  }
  button.btn.btn-primary.off-canvas-toggle{
    font-size: 28px;
  }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button.btn.btn-primary.off-canvas-toggle i.fa.fa-bars").addClass("fa-user").removeClass("fa-bars");
  });
</script>
```

When I use my browsers development tools I can see those tags in the head where they should be, but when I inspect the elements, the styles are not applied.

**Edit: the style is working now, I foolishly used the wrong type. Thank you to everyone who proposed this change.**

Concerning the script problem: I do not get any errors in the console.

**Final Edit: The problem with the script is resolved.** It was either a problem with the name of the jQuery function (`jQuery` instead of `$`) or a problem with the brackets of the document.ready function.

Comment: `<style type="text/stylesheet">` should be `<style type="text/css">` or just <style></style> is also fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSS is not working, because

```
<style type="text/stylesheet">
```

should be

```
<style type="text/css">
```

And your javascript is not working, because you did not import jQuery.

There are many ways to import jQuery, this is one of them:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The style is working now. However the script is definately not working.

Comment: Oke, I'll look in to that in a moment!

Comment: I can't find anything wrong with your code. Are any errors displayed in the console? (in most browsers you can open the console with F12)

Comment: I do not get any errors in the console.

Comment: By the way, it's a nice convention to add javascript to the bottom of your page, just before </body> if not needed by any of the DOM elements. In this particular case the javascript is even called after the DOM has loaded entirely, so it's better to add your javascript to the bottom of the page. That way, the javascript doesn't stall loading the page.

Answer (score 0):

It should be text/css

Here is the modified code.

```
<style type="text/css">
  div.t3-sidebar.t3-sidebar-right{
    background: #F8F8F8 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    border: 1px solid rgb(238, 238, 238);
    border-radius: 20px;
  }
  button.btn.btn-primary.off-canvas-toggle{
    font-size: 28px;
  }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button.btn.btn-primary.off-canvas-toggle i.fa.fa-bars").addClass("fa-user").removeClass("fa-bars");
  });
</script>
```